# Spacy infix for a set of characters

Tags: python, spacy, tokenize

I am trying to train a `Named Entity Recognition` model with `Spacy`. As a part of it, I need to convert the sentences to document for the `Spacy` model to digest both for training and prediction. Following is the initial approach I have used:

```
import spacy

# Taking a blank model
nlp = spacy.blank('xx')

# Convert a sentence to document
doc = nlp("Hafiz's e-book reader.")
```

But after printing the segments entity-wise I have got the following:

```
>>> print([t.text if not t.ent_type_ else t.ent_type_ for t in doc])
['Hafiz', "'s", 'e', '-', 'book', 'reader', '.'] # printing
```

I want `Spacy` not to split by some characters, namely: `["'", "-", "_"]`. So, I did the following:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank('xx')
skip_on = ["'", "-", "_"]
infixes = nlp.Defaults.infixes
infixes = [x for x in infixes if not set(x).intersection(set(skip_on))] # Set intersection is done just to see if any of the desired characters exist
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes).finditer
```

Now after applying it to the same sentence I have got:

```
doc = nlp("Hafiz's e-book reader.")
>>> print([t.text if not t.ent_type_ else t.ent_type_ for t in doc])
['Hafiz', "'s", 'e-book', 'reader', '.'] # printing
```

We can see, now the model properly understands that it should not split on hyphens (`e-book` remains the same).

But the problem is I cannot get the same behavior for apostrophe (See: `Hafiz's` has become `Hafiz` and `'s`). How to fix this issue?

NB: I want the following to be outputted:

```
["Hafiz's", 'e-book', 'reader', '.']
```

**Update**:
It is essentially skipping splitting for all the punctuation which are in between a text, not just the listed punctuation and symbols (`["'", "-", "_"]`):

```
doc = nlp("Hafiz's e-book reader.abc")
>>> print([t.text if not t.ent_type_ else t.ent_type_ for t in doc])       
['Hafiz', "'s", 'e-book', 'reader.abc'] # printing
```

Here, `reader.abc` should be splitted as `.` is not in the list.

Reference:
[Spacy | Modifying existing rule sets](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizer-additions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tokenizer.explain()` to see some debugging info about which tokenizer settings are leading to a particular tokenization:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank("xx")
skip_on = ["'", "-", "_"]
infixes = [x for x in nlp.Defaults.infixes if not set(x).intersection(set(skip_on))]
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes).finditer

print(nlp.tokenizer.explain("Hafiz's"))
# [('TOKEN', 'Hafiz'), ('SUFFIX', "'s")]
```

Comment: Hi, how do I get output `["Hafiz's", 'e-book', 'reader', '.']` for the input `Hafiz's e-book reader.`?